# can somebody explain me how to use TransactionManager,Transaction,XAResource?

Tags: java, transactions, jta

I am trying to understand java transaction Api. I understood i have to implement TransactionManager class which controls the transaction boundries.This transactionManager instance will be in my service class and transaction manager gives each thread a transaction object which will have a connection inside it. Now i am not getting how to give this connection object to my Dao class where I have my queries.

Comment: No, you shouldn't be implementing your own `TransactionManager`, that would be a bit too advanced for you. Containers have their own JTA providers that handle things.

Comment: I am trying to learn how JTA works..... If you could tell me how Transaction Manager,Transaction ,XAResource work together and How i can give DAO class a Connection object that will be helpful.. Thanks

Comment: That's too broad (not to mention redundant) to address here, when there's plenty of resources available on the internet.